# Is it possible to Autowire two different beans of the same class without @qualifier and @resource? If yes, how?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a component in jar fole which has a autowired DataSource

```
 @Service
 Class ReadService{
      @Autowire
       DataSource readDataSource
 }


@Service
 Class WriteService{
      @Autowire
      DataSource writeDataSource
 }
```

I have to configure two different severs, one to read and one to write.. how do I inject those DataSource to these beans created from Jar plugin...

Comment: You can only do that with `@Qualifier` or name-based using `@Resource`.

Comment: You can autowire a DataSourceFactory, that contains methods that return the correct dataSources. for instance, you autowire the factory, and call getReadService() or getWriteService(). Otherwise, you'll need the qualifier

Answer (score 1):

You can read more [here](https://springframework.guru/how-to-configure-multiple-data-sources-in-a-spring-boot-application/)

in two words, you can specify different datasource configurations in properties file and create datasource beans separately

```
app.datasource.member.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/memberdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
app.datasource.member.username=root
app.datasource.member.password=P@ssw0rd#
app.datasource.member.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
#card number  (cardholder id, cardnumber)
app.datasource.cardholder.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cardholderdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
app.datasource.cardholder.username=root
app.datasource.cardholder.password=P@ssw0rd#
app.datasource.cardholder.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
#expiration date (card id, expiration month, expiration year)
app.datasource.card.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/carddb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
app.datasource.card.username=root
app.datasource.card.password=P@ssw0rd#
app.datasource.card.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

**For primary Datasource**

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.member")
public DataSourceProperties memberDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.member.configuration")
public DataSource memberDataSource() {
    return memberDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
            .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
```

**For secondary datasource**

```
/*cardholder data source */
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.cardholder")
public DataSourceProperties cardHolderDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.cardholder.configuration")
public DataSource cardholderDataSource() {
    return cardHolderDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
            .type(BasicDataSource.class).build();
}
/*card data source*/
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.card")
public DataSourceProperties cardDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.card.configuration")
public DataSource cardDataSource() {
    return cardDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
            .type(BasicDataSource.class).build();
}
```

And specify schema in entity declaration

```
@Table(name = "member", schema = "memberdb")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you build 2 separate applications based on same component, you can simply use different database connection settings in `application.yml` (or `application.properties`) of both applications

For "Write" app:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/writeDB
    username: "username"
    password: "password"
```

For "Read" app:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/readDB
    username: "username"
    password: "password"
```